# apache-commons-config PropertiesConfiguration: comments after last property is lost

Tags: java, properties, configuration-files, apache-commons

I am using [PropertiesConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) to edit property file. This allows me to retain comments.  All works fine except for comments that comes after the last key..

For example  input file

```
# *** A comment
GameCheck.no=No
**#  end coment**
```

The output is as below. It lost comment that was after last key

```
# *** A comment
GameCheck.no = myvar
```

The code as below.

```
package trials;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfigurationLayout;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class EditVersion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            PropertiesConfiguration config =  new PropertiesConfiguration("C:\\try\\in.properties");
            config.setProperty("application.version", "myvar");
            PropertiesConfigurationLayout layout = config.getLayout();

            config.save( new FileWriter( "c:/try/out.props"));
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
}
```

Work around is to add a dummy property towards the end of file. Is there a correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that should be reported in the project's JIRA :)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CONFIGURATION

Comment: I have not filed a defect there yet :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove the `**` from the beginning of `**#  end coment**` in case it makes a difference.

Also check out whether it helps if there is an empty line just after your last actual line.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug for old versions of commons-configuration ( 1.8 <= )

Version 1.10 should solve the issue.

Download from here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/download_configuration.cgi