# change a line using 'sed" command for Java/Android

Tags: java, android, sed

I am trying to change a line using 'sed" command for Android. I have used the following commands but it is not working. Noted here, my file location is in "root" folder at Android device. I also want to change the value from 20 to 10.

```
String[] cmd = { "su", "#!/bin/bash\n", 
       "sed -i 's/p2p_oper_channel/replacing_text/g' data/misc/wifi/p2p_supplicant.conf" };

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Can anone help me about this issue?

Comment: What output are you seeing?

Comment: Actually I want to change the line only. For example, the file contains 14 lines, i need to change the line from "pattern text=20" to "text to replace=10"

Comment: You should read the data from the process's error stream to see if there are any errors `p.getErrorStream()`

Answer (score 2):

Using the `sed` command like that will only execute the substitution but it will output to `stdout`. You probably want to apply the substitution to the original file. To achieve that you need to supply an option to `sed`, the `-i` option for *inline change*.

Your command should therefor look like this:

```
sed -i 's/pattern_text=20/text_to_replace=10/g' /data/location/to/file.txt
```

**Edit**

In light if your most recent details, here's a command that ought to work:

```
sed -i 's/\(p2p_oper_channel=\)[0-9]\+/\1x/' /data/misc/wifi/p2p_supplicant.conf
```

Note that the part `\1` means insert the part between the `\(` and `\)`, i.e. the string `p2p_oper_channel` and the `x` will insert an `x`. Change the `x` to the number you want to insert instead of the current one.

This is the most flexible way, now let's take the most *static* one.

```
sed -i 's/p2p_oper_channel=[0-9]\+/p2p_oper_channel=x/' /data/misc/wifi/p2p_supplicant.conf
```

Where you, again, replace `x` with the desired value.

**Edit2**

Thanks to *Wintermute*'s input, we found out escape symbols need to be escaped in Java. Reuslting in a new `sed` function:

```
sed -i 's/p2p_oper_channel=[0-9]\\+/p2p_oper_channel=x/' /data/misc/wifi/p2p_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: Please supply your input file and your desired output, it's hard to see what's wrong without this information.

Comment: I need to change the file:
/data/misc/wifi/p2p_supplicant.conf . This file contains a line "p2p_oper_channe=1". I need to change the value from "1" to any other value I want.

Comment: Include this information in your post, and you are trying to change content of the `/data/location/to/file.txt` file. To alter `/data/misc/wifi/p2p_supplicant.conf` you need to supply it as second argument to `sed`!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your updated solution. But I'm getting a problem here, the command is showing and error "Invalid escape sequence". What should I do, please let me know...

Comment: Any idea what character he's error-ing on? You can always try to replace the `[0-9]\+` with `1` if you're sure the value is one. -- I'll add a safer way, just a second.

Comment: No, this value will change in every execute of this application. The value will change from 1 to 13 depends on user. The error is showing in "sed -i 's/\" part.

Comment: Try the last one I posted.

Comment: Sorry Bro, same problem. Please get the whole line of my command and please see is there any other error: 

String[] cmd = { "su", "#!/bin/bash\n", "sed -i 's/p2p_oper_channel=[0-13]\+/p2p_oper_channel=7/' data/misc/wifi/p2p_supplicant.conf" };

Comment: You have to escape backslashes in Java string literals. `\+` is valid for (this version of) sed but not for Java. Replace it with `\\+`. I'm also not entirely sure what you think `#!/bin/bash\n` will do as a parameter to `su`; you'll have much better luck replacing it with `-c`.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem and upvote if you deemed it a quality answer!

Comment: This command is still not changing the value :( I can add text at the end of the file using ECHO command as follows: {"su","/bin/sh", "\n", "echo "+TEXT_TO_ADD+" >> /data/misc/wifi/p2p_supplicant.conf\n"}. Is there any option to add text after "p2p_oper_channel=" using "ECHO"?

Comment: No you can not, try `sed -i 's/p2p_oper_channel=/VALUE CHANGED/' filename` to see if sed works without escape chars. Maybe we can locate the problem then.

Comment: @NayeemMorshedTushar if that sub works, I have a nice workaround for your problem so, fingers crossed!

Comment: Sorry brother, It seems like, "SED" is not working with Android. "ECHO" is working, copy a file text using "CAT" is working. But "SED" is not working, even I tried with a file at SDcard location.

Comment: Maybe the `-i` option doesn't work. Try `sed '...' file > testfile` and see if anything was written to `testfile`. Obviously you need to fill in the blanks, choose a simple substitution.

Comment: The output file "file.txt" is generated at my output location but nothing copies from the source file to "file.txt". it is totally blank.

Comment: Is there any other idea bro?

Comment: You could try [tag:awk], try something like `awk 'BEGIN{print "test"}'  > test.txt` to see if it is supported. -- `test.txt` should contain the sole word `test`.

Comment: Finally I have solved my problem. I have used this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588357/java-how-to-i-change-the-configuration-file-value-in-java-easily
Thanks a lot for your kind effort @ ShellFish